# How to use latitude and longitude anywhere in the program in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

You need to use the geodata in the  tag, in the center attribute. But React prohibits the use of js code in a block with html. I tried to pull data from promise, but I always got undefined.

```
function App() {
  var lc;
    var getLocationPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async function (position) {
              resolve([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude])
          })
  })

  getLocationPromise.then((location) => {
    lc = location
    return lc
  }).catch((err) => {
      document.white("error")
  })

    return (
          <YMaps>
           <Map className="myMap" defaultState={{ center: [34, 55], zoom: 9 }}  ></Map>
          </YMaps>
        </div>
        )
    }
    export default App;
```

Comment: By "anywhere" do you mean that all components in the app should have access to that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use react local state as shown below

```js
const [lat, setLat] = React.useState(0);
const [lng, setLng] = React.useState(0);

getLocationPromise.then((location) => {
    setLat(location[0]);
    setLng(location[1]);
}).catch((err) => {
    document.write("error")
})
```

```html
<Map className="myMap" defaultState={{ center: [lat, lng], zoom: 9 }}  ></Map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) hook ?
You should be able to reference the object from anywhere (if thats what you want to do) with React's "useEffect"and "useState" properties.

For your usecase, you should do something like this:

```
const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState(null)
useEffect(async ()=>{
  const data = await YOUR_FUNCTION() / Promise
  setGeoData(data)
},
// This one should be empty
[])
```

and then in your code, you can access the geoData and use it as you want.